# Crystal Reports suppress on several conditions

Tags: crystal-reports

I am working with CR11 and in the `Section Expert` for the `Details`. The Details are in a group. I am working on suppressing the row based on the following expression:

```
{field.Id} = previous({field.Id}) and ({@impression} = False)
```

Some records that were duplicates are remove and some are not. It is also not suppressing any of the records where the function returns `False` for that row. The function is returning correct results. Any ideas?

```
[Group 1 ] {@personnelName}
  [Detail] {id} {@datetime} {@impression}
[End Group 1]
```

In the details section some of the groups are showing only 1 record for each line and some show 10-20 lines of the same data. Sort is `asc` based on `{id}` field. The `boolean` field still shows `False`

(disclaimer- not my table design just what I have to work with, names have been changed to protect the innocent!)

{@impression}:

```
 if {Table1.type} = 40 then if {Table1.descr} = "SomeText" 
                            or {Table1.descr} = "OtherText" Then True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up grouping on the {id} field and suppressed the details. That fixed the duplicates, and the select expert fixed the functions -rather than trying to concatenate the expressions in the section expert. Thanks for helping Ryan.